# How to implement multiple generic interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface

A very simple question I assume...But how do I accomplish something like the following:

```
public class MyHandler  
   implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>,ApplicationListener<ContextStoppedEvent>
```

When I try this, it tells me: "The interface Applicationlistener cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments"

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Spring. You cannot implement the same interface (and type in brackets is erased in runtime) two times.

Comment: What I want is two methods `onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event)` and `onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event)` that get called appropiately (note that one event is the start event, the other is the end event

Comment: You can't implement the same interface twice.  The generic types are erased at runtime.  If you want to implement multiple listeners check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836073/is-it-possible-to-make-a-spring-applicationlistener-listen-for-2-or-more-types-o

Comment: That question shows that this is a duplicate, why not vote to close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it:

```
class MyHandler implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationContextEvent> {

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationContextEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextStartedEvent) {
            onContextStarted((ContextStartedEvent)event);
        }
        ...
    }

    private void onContextStarted(ContextStartedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

or create a separate handler for each event type.